In SQL, why should all non-aggregated columns in a SELECT statement be included in GROUP BY?
I came across a statement that said

When using aggregate functions (COUNT(), CASE for conditional logic), the GROUP BY clause should include all non-aggregated columns that are selected

What is the reason for this?
For example, I have a query where this is INCORRECT:
select 
    e.first_name, 
    e.last_name, 
    count(o.order_id) as num_orders, 
    (case when shipped_date <= required_date then 'On Time' else 'Late' end) as shipped
from 
    employees e
join 
    orders o on e.employee_id = o.employee_id
group by 
    e.employee_id
order by 
    last_name, first_name, num_orders desc

But this is CORRECT:
select 
    e.first_name, 
    e.last_name, 
    count(o.order_id) as num_orders, 
    (case when shipped_date <= required_date then 'On Time' else 'Late' end) as shipped
from 
    employees e
join 
    orders o on e.employee_id = o.employee_id
group by 
    e.first_name, e.last_name, shipped
order by 
    last_name, first_name, num_orders desc


In your case, if there are two different last names assigned to the same employee ID, which last name do you expect the database to return after grouping by employee ID?
That's why SQL requires that all columns in the SELECT statement that are not part of an aggregate function must be included in the GROUP BY clause to ensure each row in the result set is uniquely defined, and to ensure that the SQL query is logically consistent and unambiguous.

Also, OP defines a unit-level, non-aggregated expression for shipped, requiring another non-ambiguous grouping.
